# VBA Searching a Range

Tags: vba

Im trying to search through a range of cells with the .Find method and i can't seem to get it to work.  I have the upper bound and lower bound numbers in cells A1 and A2 and just want to search A column. Is there another way i can set up the .Range() so that i can search these specific cells?

```
 lowNum = Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, 1)
HighNumb = Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, 2)

Row = 2
While Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A" & Row))
cn = 1
While Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(Row, cn))
    Set c1 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(lowNum, "A"), Cells(HighNumb,"A")).Find(
        What:=Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(Row, cn), _
        LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c1 Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(Row, cn).Delete shift:=xlToLeft
        cn = cn - 1
    End If
    cn = cn + 1
Wend
Row = Row + 1
Wend




End Sub
```

Comment: One thing you might want to fix is this `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(lowNum, "A"), Cells(HighNumb,"A")` This should actually be `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(lowNum, "A"), Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(HighNumb,"A")` Or, as I prefer to write it for the sake of brevity `With Worksheets("Sheet2") .Range(.Cells(lowNum, "A"),.Cells(HighNumb,"A"))` You need to qualify your sheet references when using Cells inside of a Range.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean by: I have the upper bound and lower bound numbers in cells A1 and A2 and just want to search A column. Is there another way i can set up the .Range() so that i can search these specific cells? Are you looking for Integers between the numbers in cells A1 and A2 on Sheet2?

Comment: I was to search the cells between the two numbers. For example i want to search from A200:A450 for the values that i have saved in Sheet4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected your code a little, tell me if it worked:

```
lowNum = Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, 1).Value
HighNumb = Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, 2).Value

LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet4".Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

For Row = 2 To LastRow
    While Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A" & Row))
        cn = 1
        While Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(Row, cn))
            Set c1 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(lowNum, "A"), Cells(HighNumb,"A")).Find(What:=Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(Row, cn).Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not c1 Is Nothing Then
                Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(Row, cn).Delete shift:=xlToLeft
                cn = cn - 1
            End If
        cn = cn + 1
        Wend
    Row = Row + 1
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: PS: lowNum, HighNum and LastRow need to be declared as integers or a longs

Comment: Thank you this worked.  And I have them declared i just didn't copy it all sorry.

Comment: It's ok, just wanted to make sure they were declared correctly for this code. If it worked, would you mark it as answer? :)